# Java regex skip some characters match only one occurrence of digit, with intermittent periods

Tags: java, regex

My data looks like this:

```
0.1.2
[2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3]
```

I'd like to write a test that can identify the last digit in the first line, i.e. `2`, and subsequently use that to match the second digit of each value in the second line.

So from the first line it would grab `2`, and then in the second line it would grab `2`.

I've been trying to write some regex for this task using [this site](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output), I tried something like `[^\d\.\d\.]\d`... but to no avail.

Does anyone know how I could use regex to extract the `2` from the String `0.1.2`, to to extract the middle digit from such strings as `2.2.0`, and `2.2.1`?

Comment: Is it always single digits in both the first and second line?

Comment: yes, it always has the format `X.X.X` with `X` being a digit

Comment: ah, yeah- and I'm always only trying to match a single digit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use two regexes, one to get the `2` from the first line, the other to get all the triplets from the second line.

```
String s = "0.1.2\n" +
        "[2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3]";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d\\.\\d\\.(\\d)\n(.+)").matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    int lastDigit = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)); // find the last digit on first line
    String secondLine = m.group(2);

    // now find triplets on the second line
    m = Pattern.compile("(\\d)\\.(\\d)\\.(\\d)").matcher(secondLine);
    while (m.find()) {

        // here I printed the digits out. You can do whatever you like with "m.group(lastDigit)"
        System.out.println(m.group(lastDigit));
    }
}
```